# pd.read_csv and then pd.concat in parallel for multiple txt files

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, dask

I can't find anything specifically to this and can't seem to get any combo of dask or pool to do what I need without an error.

My need is to read a dozen or more txt files (in four folders so using recursive) with specific naming convention and then merge them all together. All files have the same column names but each file is different lengths.

Here is how I can do it now and have it working but want to run in parallel:

```
 path1 = my specific filepath

 file_list = glob.glob(os.path.join(path1, "*\\XT*.txt"), recursive = 
             True)

 df_each = (pd.read_csv(f, sep = '|') for f in file_list)

 df = pd.concat(df_each, ignore_index = True)
```

Then there are a few little things that need to be cleaned up and changed which I have done like this:

```
 df.replace{("#":""}, regex = True, inplace = True

 df.columns = df.columns.str.replace("#", "")
```

The end goal of what I need for all the files is a summary of the sum for each column which is grouped specifically which is done like this:

```
 df_calc = df.groupby(['Name1', 'Name2']).sum()
```

Right now it takes about 30 minutes to run and looking to run in parallel to cut this time down. Thanks!

Comment: How many total rows and columns are you loading?  Is your CPU at 100% during the entire loading process?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Total rows is ~10 million. Total columns loaded is 84 but my calculation for .sum() is only being done for 17 other columns rather than the groupby columns. Which is a good point....I could specify to only load those columns from the beginning by usecols= which would probably cut out a lot.

Comment: is the CPU or the disk the bottleneck?

Comment: Is your CPU at 100% during the entire loading process?

Comment: @JohnZwinck and CPU usage is very low and not ever even close to 100%

Comment: What is the max total memory usage of the Python process while it is loading?  How much RAM do you have?

Comment: @MaartenFabré The CPU isn't the bottleneck but the disk very well could be. I'll have to test but would say without testing that the disk is a bottleneck.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I have 128gb RAM. Max that I have seen is 40 or 45.

Comment: If the disk is the bottleneck, throwing more CPU-power at it will not help

Comment: If this is something that needs to be done repetitively, try to parse the `.txt` files once and then save them in an intermediate storage as a more performant format (`hdfs` or `feather`?) which you load at the analysis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in a comment that your CPU utilization is low, not near 100%.  This means that you are being limited by disk throughput or memory bandwidth.  So assigning more CPU cores to work on this task will only slow it down.  Instead, you should focus on reducing the IO and the memory consumption.

Using the `usecols` option of `pd.read_csv()` is a great start.  Also, try passing `engine='c'` and an explicit `dtype` to avoid Pandas having to guess the dtype each time.

You might also benefit from an SSD.

You should also consider storing your data in a more efficient format.  For example the format produced by `np.save()` and friends.  This could speed up loading by 100x.